# Print does't work in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running Python in Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC. I have installed [the Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Mixed-mode%20debugging), which comes with Python 3.3.

I am just doing a very simple print statement, but it reports Syntax Error.

```
print 'aaa'
```

Also, after I enter <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the interpreter refuses to print `aaa` out.
The screenshot is as follows:

[image]

**Error message** from the interpreter:

```
>>> print '1
... '
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 627, in run_one_command
    self.execute_item()
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 601, in execute_code_work_item
    code = compile(self.current_code, '<stdin>', 'single', self.code_flags)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print '1
           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> a=1
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 627, in run_one_command
    self.execute_item()
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 601, in execute_code_work_item
    code = compile(self.current_code, '<stdin>', 'single', self.code_flags)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print a
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I used to play around with Python 2.7. Why is it so in 3.3?

Comment: It would be wise to read the changelog when switching between major version of anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`print` is no longer a statement in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), is it a *function* [`print()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print), hence the correct syntax is:

```
print('aaa')
```